# IBM Cognos reports decommissioning - UI or UNIX solution

Tags: sql, unix, cognos, cognos-10

We have some old reports which are not being used anymore by the business and wish to remove/archive these.

I have 2 queries related to this:

a) What is the best way to find if a report has not been used for the past 12+ months?

b) Is there any simple way of moving the reports no longer being used (not used for > 12 months) to a different location (i.e. new folder), while keeping the folder structure intact?

We have searched for solutions on the web, but have not been able to find an automated solution for this. as the number of reports which we have figured out is in the range of ~5000, we are searching for an automated way to work this out.

Would running an SQL query on the server (physical machine) be advisable? If we run this query on the content store, we wish to figure out the column/field on which the actual report lies (in the below query have used , but not sure if such a field or query can be used):

```
update <table> set <report_path>='/content/folder[@name='Home']/folder[@name='Report']/report[@name='ABC012 - My Report']' where <report_path>='/content/folder[@name='Home']/folder[@name='Archive_test']/report[@name='ABC012 - My Report']'
```

Would this kind of a query work?

If not, can anyone suggest a way on which we can move reports to a single  folder on the same Cognos box? (we are using Cognos 10, with DB2 and Netezza)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you with a)
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cfpm/v10r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_cra.10.1.0.doc%2Fug_cra_id4425SampleAuditReports.html
You can use provided package and sample reports to find information you need.

And for b) you should look in Cognos SDK. I don't think that update tables directly is a good idea.

Comment: A word of caution, make sure your licenses are in compliance before enabling your Audit Database.  IBM will review the Audit Database to track your license usage if you are ever Audited, and eventually all Cognos customers get Audited by IBM.